# Hibernate 5 + Non JTA datasource: object not being stored

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, persistence, datasource

I'm facing a problem and have no idea what's going wrong. The cenary:

- Hibernate 5
- Apache Tomcat 9
- JSF 2

No Spring.  It's important to say because I saw this problem happening realted with Spring use, but this is not my case.

The datasource was correctly configured on Tomcat, and the Hibernate also creates the tables and update schemma correctly for each new Entity.

The problem is when I try to persist a new Entity, nothing happens.  Then I tried to include "flush()" call... but then I've got an error saying I have no transaction active:

***javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress***

It seems to be a problem related with a transaction requirement, but I have also tried:

- include "@Transactional" annotation on method;
- include "@Transactional" annotation on class;
- Force begin transaction with "beginTransaction()" call but then I've got a NullPointer;

So... I don't know what do to.

Follow you'll see my relevant code.  Can you help me to solve this problem?

***persistence.xml file:***

`<persistence-unit name="hospitalPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <description>
            Persistence unit for Hibernate
        </description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/hospitalDatasource</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.default_catalog" value="hospital" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/hospitalDatasource"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>`

***My Entity:***

```
@Entity(name="Dominio")
@Table(name="Dominio")
public class Dominio implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

here goes another fileds and getters/setters...
```

***On my managed bean, I have:***

```
@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

***And:***

```
protected synchronized EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    if (emf == null) {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hospitalPU");
    }
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

It seems to work fine, but the problem happens here:

***With this, nothing happen and no Exception occours.  Just NOTHING happens:***

```
getEntityManager().persist(getDominio());
```

***With this, I have "javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress":***

```
getEntityManager().persist(getDominio());
getEntityManager().flush(); //exception occours here!
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for you all!

Answer (score 0):

you need to more configure the `persistence.xml` or `hibernate.cfg.xml`. you can refer bellow link to configure these xml files.

https://gist.github.com/imanoleizaguirre/3819393

http://www.journaldev.com/7122/jsf-spring-hibernate-integration-example-tutorial

http://www.javaknowledge.info/simple-crud-using-jsf2hibernate-integration-and-mysql/

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply @Mayank.
But didn´t work for me.  I've follwed this recomendation and got the same error:
https://gist.github.com/imanoleizaguirre/3819393

The second and third links do not apply to my case because it refers to use Spring or an older version of JPA / Hibernate.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This one here clearly explains what is the problem:
**"javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress"**

First, you have clearly mentioned that you are using a Non-JTA datasource. meaning that the container will no longer manage for you transaction boundaries. You must begin and commit/rollback transactions on your own. You therefore need to follow the following:

```
EntityManager em = ....
EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
try {
    et.begin();
    em.persist(entity);
    et.commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    et.rollback();
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
```